# Change value for an object in an R environment in a for loop

Tags: r, eval, environment, nls

I am trying to change the value of an object in R environment. The code is given thus. and the error message:

```
myco <- function(form, data, start,tol=1e-06,maxit=10000)
{
  env <- new.env(hash = TRUE, parent = environment(form))
  for(i in names(data)) assign(i, data[[i]], envir = env,inherit=T)
  ind <- as.list(start)
  assign("new",ind,envir=env,inherit=T)
  
  
  for(itr in 1:maxit){
    assign("old",new,envir=env,inherit=T)
    grad=deriv(expr=form[[3L]],names(ind))
    attr(eval(grad,envir=env),"gradient")->J
    yh=eval(form[[2L]],env)-eval(form[[3L]],env)
    new=old+MASS::ginv(t(J)%*%J)%*%t(J)%*%yh
    if(sum(abs(new-old))<tol) break
    
  }
  return(new)
}

myco(GDP~A*(Labor^c)*(Capital^b),data=dat,start=list(A=0.05,b=0.5,c=0.5))
```

and the error message is

> Error in assign("new", ind, envir = env, inherit = T) :
> cannot change value of locked binding for 'new'

Comment: Please define all variables like `dat` so that we can copy/paste the code to run it and debug it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code? Why are you creating all these environments?

Comment: form is formular

Comment: we cannot debug anything if we dont know what data is passed to function; you need to provide at least stubs which are identical to your data

Comment: data is a dataframe object, start is a list object that contains the initial parameters, tol is a scalar (the tolerance value) and maxit is the maximum iteration, a scalar also

Comment: This function does not make sense (to me). Why are you assigning `data[[i]]` to `i` with `assign(i, data[[i]], envir = env,inherit=T)`? A for-loop iterates over data, with every loop changing the value of `i` through the vector `names(data)`. You should not assign `i` within the loop. Also, `<-` should be used for assignment.

Comment: @Teniola why are you doing `as.list()` on an already `list` parameter? (line 5)

Comment: @Teniola your whole iteration loop makes no sense, as it doesnt iterate over any parameter; it simply does 10000 times the same operation, overwriting your `new` variable each time; also, assigning variable INSIDE the loop is a bad habit, especially if you are going to `return` it - which you do